# itext7 pdfhtml 2.0.2 no backgrounds and borders

Tags: java, itext7, pdfhtml

Cannot find any docs, please help.
I am trying to generate  simple pdf from html string using itext 7/pdfhtml 2.0.2 and cannot make it to render backgrounds and borders. Just see empty pdf with texts only - no backgrounds and borders. Maybe there's a parameter or something? Here's the code I found on the itext site (tried bot with and without ConverterProperties#setBaseUri):

```
    OutputStream os=resp.getOutputStream();

    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    properties.setBaseUri(url.toString());
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os,
            new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true));
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(buf.toString(), writer, properties);
    os.close();
```

The html is simple: just one div, and css for it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/html2pdf.css' />
    <title>
        HTML 2 PDF
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="rightruler"></div>
    <div id="infoBox0" class="infoItem resizey" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; display: block; margin: 0px; left: 633px; top: 2

</body>
```

And css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: helv-light;
    src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuelight-webfont.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: helv;
    src: url("../fonts/helveticaneue-webfont.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: helv-medium;
    src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: helv-bold;
    src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuebold-webfont.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    font-family: helv-light;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #555555;
}
div#maincontainer
{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #555555;
    color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #774400;
}
div.infoItem
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    height: 4em;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: .5em;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue is with finding the css file. Where do you place it relatively to your HTML file? Which base URI have you set when used `ConverterProperties#setBaseUri`?

Please, keep also in mind that the CSS file URI in your HTML file (`/css/html2pdf.css`) has leading slash in it. According to URI processing, relative URI with leading slash identify paths based from the root of the base URI, for example: "c:/your/base/path" + "/relative/path/css.file" resolves to "c:/relative/path/css.file". Is it what you expect?

Comment: @YulianGaponenko well, i see it rendered fine in browsers, and older (opensource 2.1.7) itext and openhtmlpdf renders it fine as well. Is there any special requirements? Tried different base uri as well as not to set it - the result is the same, no colors

Comment: Once again, could you elaborate more on what structure of files you have, i.e. where is the HTML file and where is CSS file?
E.g. when HTML file is in folder `c:/test/html2pdf.html` and CSS file is in `c:/test/css/html2pdf.css` and in HTML I specify path to CSS as `css/html2pdf.css` (mind no leading slashes) - pdfHTML works fine for me.

However when I add leading slash to HTML while preserving the same files structure, CSS styles (borders and background) are not found and not applied both for pdfHTML and browsers (latest versions of Chrome and Firefox). Tested without setting any baseURI.

Comment: BTW, your snippet contains malformed HTML.

Comment: @YulianGaponenko Files are on server, as I said, old itext and openhtml2pdf works almost fine with the same html/css. Could you pls tell me what's wrong with html?

Comment: @YulianGaponenko Just checked - I pass full url in the html. like        "http://server/css/style.css" and the same for ConverterProperties#setBaseUri

Comment: `http://server/css/style.css`, sorry, stackoverflow thinks it's an anchor )

Comment: @YulianGaponenko Btw, do you know, is there a way to check, did itext found the css or not? Some kind of debug?

Comment: Btw, I see setbaseUri is not used at all:
`public IDocumentNode parse(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    INode result = this.wrapJsoupHierarchy(doc);
    if (result instanceof IDocumentNode) {
        return (IDocumentNode)result;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}`